# Cannot throw custom exception using orElseThrow in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception, option-type, conditional-operator

I am trying to throw a custom exception using ternary operation and `orElseThrow` as shown below:

```
public static MainProviderType getMainProviderType(ProviderType providerType) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(MainProviderType.valueOf(providerType.name()))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ProviderTypeNotFoundException(providerType.name()));
}
```

However, when `providerType` is null, this method returns `NullPointerException` rather than `ProviderTypeNotFoundException`. I think the problem is related to that; it cannot evaluate `MainProviderType.valueOf(providerType.name())` because `providerType.name()`. Is that true? And how should I use it and fix the problem?

Comment: If your `providerType` is null then `providerType.name()` will always throw the NullPointerException

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @NagarajuChitimilla I know that

Comment: Is ProviderType a part of MainProviderType? Does the names from ProviderType exist on MainProviderType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static MainProviderType getMainProviderType(ProviderType providerType) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(providerType)
    .map(ProviderType::name)
    .map(MainProviderType::valueOf)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ProviderTypeNotFoundException("some message"));
}
```

**Update** Full example with test case

```
    private enum ProviderType {
        ONE,
        TWO
    }

    private enum MainProviderType {
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
    }

    public MainProviderType getMainProviderType(ProviderType providerType) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(providerType)
            .map(ProviderType::name)
            .map(MainProviderType::valueOf)
            .orElseThrow();
    }

    @Test
    void selectMainProviderType() {
        var mainProviderType = getMainProviderType(ProviderType.ONE);

        assertEquals(MainProviderType.ONE, mainProviderType);
    }
```

Comment: Won't that last dereference of providerType still throw an NPE?

Comment: Yes you're right. Too quick to answer :-) Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried but have a little problem related to **valueOf**:  "Reference to 'valueOf' is ambiguous, both 'valueOf(String)' and 'valueOf(Class<T>, String)' match"

Comment: I think I should add `.name()` like `return Optional.ofNullable(providerType.name()).map(MainProviderType::valueOf)`

Comment: You need to do that after checking if providerType is null somehow, otherwise you will end up in a NullPointerException

Comment: An other question. I noticed you have ProvderType and MainProviderType - does all names from ProviderType exist on MainProviderType?

Comment: Do you mean that using `Optional.ofNullable(providerType.name()).map(MainProviderType::valueOf)` is not true? In this case, how to fix the error I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: For your question, yes thats's true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235962/discussion-between-tomas-f-and-rosa).

Comment: Your last update seems to work, is not it?

Comment: @TomasF And What about using `ProviderType.class.getSimpleName()` instead of `providerType.name()`. Because when `providerType` is null, it is meaningless to try to get its name value. So, is it logical for passing name to the custom exception?

Comment: I tried to start a chat before :-) getSimpleName would give you name name of the actual class, not the name of the enum.  I'm not really sure why it does not work in your circumstance, when i set up a test with the code above it works fine...

Comment: Could you please post the test methods with 2 methods (passing parameter and passing null)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the `providerType.name()`. If the `providerType` is `null`, then your code will work like this: `null.name()`. This makes no sense and a `NullPointerException` will always be thrown when `providerType` is `null`

You could check if the `providerType` is null before continuing to everything else:

```java
if(providerType == null)
{
    throw ProviderTypeNotFoundException(..);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`orElseThrow()` only works on the Optional's value. Your code might fail trying to create the Optional instance or might fail when constructing the exception by invoking `.name()` on a potential null object.. It could be rewritten by separating each expression into a statement, which gives the equivalent form:

```
var name = providerType.name(); // nullpointer! providerType can be null
var type = MainProviderType.valueOf(name); // nullpointer! name can be null
var optional = Optional.ofNullable(type);
return optional.orElseThrow(() -> new ProviderTypeNotFoundException(providerType.name())); // nullpointer! providerType can still be null
```

Either check for nullness of providerType and its name or create the Optional earlier and then apply each transformation via map:

```
public static MainProviderType getMainProviderType(ProviderType providerType) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(providerType)
            .map(ProviderType::name)
            .map(MainProviderType::valueOf)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ProviderTypeNotFoundException(providerType != null ? providerType.name() : "no name"));
}
```

Comment: Name can only be null in the first code block if MainProviderType would not be an enum right?

Comment: @TomasF I don't understand your question. `name` could be null and assuming `MainProviderType` is an enum, its `valueOf` method will throw a NullPointerException. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No. In the first code block - if provderType is not null, and MainProviderType is an enum, then providerType.name() would not be able to return null right? So the second line could only give a NPE in cases where MainProviderType is not an enum. (but in this case it probably is)

Comment: @Rosa that's for you to find out, it is your code. I cannot run nor test it. With the limited information provided, it is very likely to throw a NullPointerException in one of the commented expressions in my answer. Best to start up a debugger, set a breakpoint and step through the code to see where exactly the exception is thrown.

Comment: What about using `ProviderType.class.getSimpleName()` instead of `providerType.name()`. Because when `providerType` is null, it is meaningless to try to get its name value. So, is it logical for passing name to the custom exception?

Comment: @Rosa `ProviderType.class.getSimpleName()` will return the `"ProviderType"`. If you need that, you can directly write the string literal `"ProviderType"` directly in your code. `providerType.name()` returns the whatever the method `name()` returns on this specific object _instance_ of the class.